# How can I access a variable from another class in python?

Tags: python, kivy

I need to access the user_objectid from the LoginScreen class and use it to access that user's high scores for a game using the Parse SDK in the HighScore class. However, I'm not sure how to access this information. Below is my code:

```
    class LoginScreen(Screen):

       def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
          self.gametime = BooleanProperty(False)

       _username = ObjectProperty(None)
       _password = ObjectProperty(None)
       user_objectid = ObjectProperty(None)

       def loginUser(self):

          if self._username.text != '' and self._password.text != '':
             try:
                connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
                params = urllib.urlencode({"username":self._username.text,            "password":self._password.text})
                connection.connect()
                connection.request('GET', '/1/login?%s' % params, '', {
                   "X-Parse-Application-Id": "${APPLICATION_ID}",
                   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "${REST_API_KEY}",
                   "Content-Type": "application/json"
                })
                result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
                # Confirm valid user
                if result['objectId'] != '':
                   self.user_objectid = result['objectId']
                   return True
```

This is the code for the HighScore class:

```
    class HighScore(Screen):
       def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super(HighScore, self).__init__(**kwargs)

          # Need user_objectid from LoginScreen class here!
          user_id = ObjectProperty()


          connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
          connection.connect()
          connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/GameScore/user_id', '', {
             "X-Parse-Application-Id": "${APPLICATION_ID}",
             "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "${REST_API_KEY}"
          })
          result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
          print result['score']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you twice define properties in the class `__init__` functions. This will *not* give property behaviour, they *must* be defined at class level for them to work as properties (and not just normal attributes).

For your main question, the answer is simply that your HighScore instance needs a reference to your LoginScreen instance - if it has that, say in the variable `lgs`, you can simply access `lgs.user_objectid` to get the value you want.

The best way to do this depends entirely on the structure of your program, and where you create and use those classes and their methods.